# Add a card to a user using a card id in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

There was a bug in our system for a few days which meant we were taking payments on Stripe but weren't joining the card to the new customer. We need the card to be attached to the customer so that we can charge them again.

Knowing only the card information from the first charge (ie card_123) is it possible for me to add the card to the customer?

From what I see, I need a token to be able to do this and to generate a token I need the raw card data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created the charge directly with a card token in the `source` parameter, then it's not possible to retrieve the card data afterwards and attach it to a customer object.

You will have to ask your customers to provide their card information again, generate a new token, and attach this token to customer objects.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that was the case but just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything